# T-SQL group specific items at the top of return

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm pulling a list of employees from a db and they each have an office ID. I want to order by the office ID but want the current office of the user to appear at the top of the list and the rest to appear below in the order ascending order.

```
Example:

Name  Office
Mike    1
Alex    2
John    6
Steve   2
Sarah   3

If my office is office 2, I want those to appear at the top like so

Name  Office
Alex    2
Steve   2
Mike    1
Sarah   3
John    6
```

Is there a way to do this in some type of clause or would I have to create a temp table, do the first search on only the specific office ID and then add the rest to the table where its not the same as that ID. I feel like that's a complete hack and would prefer not to do that if not needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `case` in an `order by` and therefore alter the position:

```
select * 
from table
order by 
case when Office = 2 then 0 else Office end
```

You could, of course, parameterize the `2` in the above

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from yourTable
where OfficeId = 2
union all
select *
from yourTable
where OfficeId <> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from yourTable
ORDER BY CASE
       WHEN OfficeID = 2 THEN 0
       ELSE 1
  END
, OfficeID
```